# How do I create a key binding shortcut to run a custom package / plugin in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have Markdown preview package installed in my sublime text and I want to create a shortcut / key binding for it, let's say:
`ctrl + shift + p`

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+P` is already assigned to the Command Palette...

Comment: Not in Mac, that is `Command+Shift+P`.
It could be any other key set. I just want to run a package / plugin that you'd normally do by opening control package and typing the command name there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the ST console, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` to see what command is being executed form the command palette. Alternatively you can look in the `Default.sublime-menu` file for the appropriate caption/command pair. After you've done that, you can create a custom key binding. To do this, open your user key binding file by going to `Preferences -> Key Binding - User`. Enter something like the following.

```
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+p"], "command": "<preview_command_here>"}
]
```

The settings file is just a list, so if you already have an entry, you do not need the square brackets.

Comment: For custom packages, command name is the package name so you'll need extra args: 

"keys": ["command+shift+0"], "command": "corona_debugger", "args": {"cmd": "setb"}